# Visual Studio says -> Imports 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found

Tags: excel, vb.net, import, visual-studio-code

I have the following code written in Visual Studio Code that gives the error: warning BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Background on my code: I am making a 9-digit serial number for each unit that is built in a manufacturing facility that will have an output like Z01230000 where:

Z is a constant,
0 is the build year (0 starts at 2014, so 2019 will be 5),
123 is the 3-digit day of when the unit is built,
0000 is the build number for the day.

Example: If we build 100 units for the entire day, then the serial number would be Z01230100.

I have the following code which works. I would now like to import from an Excel 365 file (.xlsm) that reads from the 1st tab, and from my "Quantity" column within this file:

`````
````
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Module VBModule

Sub Main()

    'Z'
    Dim mfgLine As String
    mfgLine = "Z"

    'Single Digit Year. 2014 = 0, 2019 = 5
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim startYear As Integer
    startDate = #1/1/2014#
    startYear = Year(startDate)

    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim currentYear As Integer
    currentDate = Today
    currentYear = Year(Today)

    Dim mfgYear As Integer
    mfgYear = currentYear - startYear

    '3 digit day of year
    Dim ddd As Integer
    ddd = DateTime.Now.DayOfYear

    '4-digit quantity
    Dim qty As Integer = 1234
    Dim bldQty As String = Format(qty,"0000")

    'Concatenate serial number
    Dim serialNum As String
    serialNum = mfgLine & mfgYear & ddd & bldQty
    Console.Write(serialNum)

End Sub
`````

End Module
    ````

Note: Where I have 'Dim qty As Integer = 1234' written, this was just for me to ensure that my serial number was concatenating correctly. It is around here that I would like to import my Excel file with the correct qty amount from my desired column.

Comment: Have you added the appropriate reference to your project? There's no use importing a namespace if you haven't referenced a library containing any types in that namespace.

Comment: Is there a reason I would get an error even though I haven't referenced the Excel file anywhere? I didn't think having Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel would hurt anything even if I hadn't referenced my Excel file just yet.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else running into the same issue like me - After googling, adding Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel via NuGet solved the problem.